# Determine Which JTable Cell is Clicked

Tags: java, swing, jtable, listener

When a user clicks a cell on a `JTable`, how do I figure out the row and column of the clicked cell?  How would I show this information in a `JLabel`?

Answer (score 35):

The existing answer works, but there is an alternate method that may work better if you're not enabling cell selection. Inside your `MouseListener`, do something like this:

```
public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent event) {
    int row = theTable.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint());
    int col = theTable.columnAtPoint(event.getPoint());
    // ...
```

Comment: Props for this answer.
getSelectedRow() or getSelectedColumn() don't work when using right click.

Comment: Like (almost) all of Java Swing "solutions", sorcks: Sucks, but works.

Answer (score 17):

You can use following methods on JTable to retrieve row and column of the selected cell:

```
int rowIndex = table.getSelectedRow();
int colIndex = table.getSelectedColumn();
```

And add a `SelectionListener` to table to catch the event when the table is selected.

Comment: +1, except the ListSelectionListener is added to the ListSelectionModel, not the JTable.

Comment: You also might wanna add a ListSelectionListener to the JTable's ColumnModel in case selected row stays the same but selected column changes: table.getColumnModel().getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(...);

Answer (score 5):

It is working for me!!!

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
@Override
 public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    int row = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    int col = jTable1.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
    if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {


    }
 }
});
```

Comment: This solution acknowledges the possibility of clicking the empty space in the JTable component.

Answer (score 1):

did you try `addMouseListener()`? I hope you are about using Swing's JTable.

Comment: yes I'm using Swing's and no, I haven't tried addMouseListener. will try right now... thanks.

Comment: this is kinda confusing, could you give some pointers or some links? I've been searching and no result. I just want the row & column of selected jTable CELL to be added in a jLabel.....

Comment: I don't think is a good way to tackle the issue.  The MouseEvent will not be that easy to convert to a column and row.  See Develman's answer.

Comment: I did not mean to add mouse listener to the table itself. Typically table cell is represented by some swing component managed by table model. I suggest to add listener to this component.

Comment: -1, A cell is represented by painting an image of a component, called a renderer. You can't add a listener to the renderer since it is not a real component. If you where to use a MouseListener it would indeed need to be added to the table, but there is no need to do this since this is the purpose of the ListSelectionListener.

Answer (score 1):

I've found that when columns are hidden/reordered `columnAtPoint` returns the visible column index, which isn't what I needed. Code which worked for me is

```
int row = theTable.convertRowIndexToModel(theTable.rowAtPoint(event.getPoint()));
int col = theTable.convertColumnIndexToModel(theTable.columnAtPoint(event.getPoint()));
```