# How can I determine which cell in a JTable was selected?

Tags: java, swing, events, jtable, listener

I have a `JTable` in a GUI and I want to return a number based on the value of the cell that a user clicks on. This is the code:

```
ListSelectionModel newmodel = mytable.getSelectionModel();
newmodel.addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener() {
    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        int row = mytable.getSelectedRow();
        int column = mytable.getSelectedColumn();

        int cell = getNewNum();
        datefield.setText(String.valueOf(cell));
    }
});
```

I have a couple of problems with this. Firstly this method makes my table editable. Before I used this method I couldn't edit the table but now I can delete entries. I looked in the API but I don't know why this is. Secondly, if I click on a cell in row 3, say, and then I click on another row in cell 3, no event is registered. How can I make an event from clicking in a cell on the currently selected row?

Comment: Adding a ListSelectionListener will NOT make your table editable. Editability of a cell is controlled by the isCellEditable(...) method of the TableModel or the JTable itself.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I check which JTable cell has been clicked/selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795586/how-can-i-check-which-jtable-cell-has-been-clicked-selected)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A common method is to get the point where the user clicked through the event:

```
jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        int row = jTable1.rowAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        int col = jTable1.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint());
        if (row >= 0 && col >= 0) {
            ......

        }
    }
});
```

Here is a second option using selection mode:

```
jTable1.setSelectionMode(javax.swing.ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
    jTable1.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
       @Override
       public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
           ...
           int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
           int col = jTable1.getSelectedColumn());
           if (evt.getClickCount() > 1) { // double-click etc...
              ...
```

If you go:

```
public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col) {
   return false;
}
```

Then your JTable will not be editable.

Finally in order to get the value you want, you just need to call the `getValueAt(row,col)` of your JTable Model, or get the contents like this:

```
Object foo = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(row, col);
```

Comment: I like your first solution, it is what I use

Comment: Will the `getSelectedRow` return the pre-selection or post-selection value? i.e., will the `MouseListener#mouseClicked` event fire before the selection change is made?

Comment: Also, `jTable1.getModel().getValueAt` will return the model value, but does `getSelectedRow()` return the row from the model or the row from the view?