# How to refer to the first column of a JTABLE and add action for each row clicked on in that column?

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, jtable

I am very new to programming and apologise if this is a very dumb question.
I have a table with columns- audio(Blob), title and artist name. I want the user to be able to play the song if they press the audio cell and then the play button.
I am having a difficult time trying to refer to the specific column-row where the audio is saved.
This is the link i have been trying to learn from but i am not getting anywhere. [How can I determine which cell in a JTable was selected?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5044222/how-can-i-determine-which-cell-in-a-jtable-was-selected) . How do I refer to the items so when row 1 is clicked then extract the audio from that file so it can play? Would i write a for loop? I know how to play the song, I just can't get it to refer to the index itself.
English is not my first language so sorry if this isn't explained very well.

EDIT:

```
`JTable table;
 File sound;
 AudioInputStream ais;
 Clip clip;
 table.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    try{
          int row = table.getSelectedRow();
          String selectedItem=(String) table.getValueAt(row,0);
           sound= new File(selectedItem);
            ais= AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(sound);
            clip= AudioSystem.getClip();
            clip.open(ais);
            clip.start();
        }

    catch(Exception exp ){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, exp);
    }       
    }});
```

When i click on the row,I wanted it to play the song but instead I get an fileNotFoundException.Is the method of extracting the file not correct?

Comment: This is not a correct format for a question in stack-overflow. Please read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to play the song in a separate thread or you'll freeze the GUI.  Java sound only works with WAV files.

Answer (score 1):

> I just can't get it to refer to the index itself.

I don't understand the problem.

You saw from the other posting you can use:

```
int row = table.getSelectedRow();
```

You load the data into your table you know what column contains the filename of the song you want to play, so you just do:

```
String filename = table.getValueAt(row, ???);
```

> I know how to play the song

So then you play the song.

Comment: @atima, My answer doesn't change. I still don't understand your problem. You know which row is select. You know where the data is in your TableModel. So when you click the button you get the selected row, then you get the filename, then you load the file and play the song. Post your [mcve] that show a frame with a table and a button. When you click on the button simply display the filename in the selected row. Once you get that working then you add the logic to play the song.

Comment: @camickr I think [this](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/07/12/table-button-column/) is what they are trying to achieve