# Get the value of a specific cell of JTable with mouse clicking

Tags: java, swing

[image]
I have a `JTable` and Given such codes:

```
jTable.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
               public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e){

                   System.out.println(jTable.getRowCount());
                   System.out.println(jTable.getModel().getValueAt(jTable.getRowCount(), 0));
               }
           });
```

If I click on a certain row, like in the picture above, I clicked the second row, how can I get that row's content?(How to get the Canada)?

Comment: Why not use `ListSelectionListener`?

Comment: Agree with Radiodef, a ListSelectionListener attached to the ColumnModel would be a safer approach. It is unlikely that the selection will have changed when the MouseListener is called

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Which JTable Cell is Clicked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795586/determine-which-jtable-cell-is-clicked)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I use the Mouse Clicked event. You could try something like this inside your event method:

```
private void myTableMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                          
    int row = this.myTable.getSelectedRow();
    int column = this.myTable.getSelectedColumn();
    this.myTable.getValueAt(selectedRow, selectedColumn);
}
```

Be aware that the `getValueAt` method returns an Object. You probably will need to cast the Object returned into the object it is supposed to be. And also you could have a global variable that's going to have the value returned by `getValueAt` for using it as you need.

I hope it helps.

Comment: It's likely that the selection hasn't changed yet, as your MouseListener is probably been called before the tables, resulting in the incorrect cell been retrieved